# Android ProGuard retrace

Tags: android, proguard

I have following stacktrace, but ProGuard doesn't retrace it correctly with the corresponding mapping.txt. How can I find out, the com.example.app.util.d.d.a function?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.app/com.example.app.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.app.util.d.d.a(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3881)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.app.util.d.d.a(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.app.MyActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3877)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Can not you find it from its signature ? `(int, int, android.content.Intent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own fake stack trace an retrace it.

In your case this line should do the trick:

```
at com.example.app.util.d.d.a(int, int, android.content.Intent)
```

Comment: It's not the best solution, but it works in some way. 
With that, I also have to check the signature `(int, int, android.content.Intent)`. Now I also configured ProGuard to save the line numbers. This is the better way to find the crash, than retracing.